# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hello.bundle.js' in 'D:\webpackDemo'

Tags: webpack-4

I am new to webpack.my situation is that: i try to use webpack for managing hello.js file.

hello.js

```
     function hello(str){
        alert(str); 
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpackdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

when i used

```
webpack hello.js hello.bundle.js
```

I get error in webstorm terminal

```
ERROR in multi ./hello.js hello.bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hello.bundle.js' in 'D:\webpackDemo'
 @ multi ./hello.js hello.bundle.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like, that the documentation is outdated, but try it like this using the `-o` flag (output.filename):

```
webpack ./hello.js -o hello.bundle.js --mode development
```

Use `--mode production` for production.